# Add correct repositories based on Ubuntu version to sources.list

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a script that installs all programs I need in case of a fresh install. Some of these need external repositories. As an example, I want to add the correct repository to the sources.list and then install the program. 
So far I have this:

```
source /etc/os-release

link="http://qgis.org/debian $UBUNTU_CODENAME main"

a='echo "deb $link" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

b='echo "deb-src $link" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

sudo sh -c $a
sudo sh -c $b
```

The concatenation part does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: The double quotes in `a` and `b` are literal, not syntactial. See [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Try `set -x` to see what the shell tries to execute.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the simple approach:

```
source /etc/os-release
{
  sudo deb http://qgis.org/debian "$UBUNTO_CODENAME" main
  sudo deb-src http://qgis.org/debian "$UBUNTO_CODENAME" main
} >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you feel the need to refactor, define a shell function:

```
get_package_list () {
    sudo "$1" http://qgis.org/debian "$UBUNTU_CODENAME" main
}

{ get_package_list deb
  get_package_list deb-src
} >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```